# Time formatting from UTC with Moment.js

Tags: javascript, codepen

How do I convert a utc time to this format using moment.js

`"YYYY Do MM hh:mm:ss"`

I am trying to follow and use this method which is in the "Parse a date" portion of the following tutorial: https://flaviocopes.com/momentjs/

```
moment(dt).format("YYYY Do MM hh:mm:ss");
```

But it just makes the date disappear.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/centem/pen/ExYEoLj

```js
var options = {
  valueNames: ['date', 'number']
};
var ResultDiv = new List('ResultDiv', options);
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}

span {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.js/1.5.0/list.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>


<div id="ResultDiv">
  <input class="search" placeholder="Search" />
  <button class="sort" data-sort="date">
    Sort by Date
  </button>
  <button class="sort" data-sort="number">
    Sort by Number
  </button>
  <button>Last 7 Days</button>
  <button>Last 30 Days</button>

  <ul class="list" id="ul">
    <li>
      <span class="2019-01">
          <script>
            let dt = new Date("2019-04-15T15:10:45Z");
            document.write(dt);
            //2019-04-15T15:10:45Z;
            //moment(dt).format("YYYY Do MM hh:mm:ss");
          </script>
            </span>
      <span class="number">76</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="date">2019-02-12T11:21:10Z</span>
      <span class="number">23</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="date">2019-01-12T10:20:16Z</span>
      <span class="number">14</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="date">2019-01-09T09:20:16Z</span>
      <span class="number">7</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="date">2019-07-11T11:01:05Z</span>
      <span class="number">101</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="date">2019-08-29T11:01:05Z</span>
      <span class="number">121</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="date">2019-09-11T11:01:05Z</span>
      <span class="number">130</span>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Solution:

```
 let current_datetime = new Date("2019-04-15T15:10:45Z")
        let formatted_date = current_datetime.getFullYear() + "-" + (current_datetime.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + current_datetime.getDate() + " " + current_datetime.getHours() + ":" + current_datetime.getMinutes() + ":" + current_datetime.getSeconds() 
        console.log(formatted_date)

        let dt = new Date("2019-04-15T15:10:45Z");
        document.write(formatted_date);
```

Comment: You do not really need o codepen for this as you are only showing 1 line here. Please convert your code to a running snippet instead (CTRL-M).

Comment: @Igor A little more than a one-liner :)

Comment: Please update the snippet I made you with the issue you are asking about.

Comment: @mplungjan - the question originally showed one line of code with the error description that "it disappeared." My assumption was that one line of code was what the user was asking about and hoped they could abstract/remove the rest of the irrelevant code from the codepen.

Comment: Not me, that was @mplungjan who updated your question.

Comment: I updated my post with the solution.

Comment: Feel free to delete the question. It does not make any sense with the code I copied from your pen

Comment: But also the solution is strange. You should be padding some single digit numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that `momentjs` isn't loaded when your `<script>` tag is called. CodePen loads JavaScript after the DOM has loaded. You need to move your code into the JavaScript portion of your CodePen. I recommend adding the date to your node and querying for those nodes, updating the node's content via innerText. I've updated your pen: https://codepen.io/kkirby/pen/zYOWJxX